# Using images in Rally Apps

Tags: rally, appsdk2

In the past I have incorporated some images that exist on the Rally server into my Apps-- for example I made a more generic "picker" menu that displays checkboxes, which of course rely on images for the checks and boxes.

Of course I would expect to have to check if any images I am using persist when the SDK version changes, but it never-the-less allows for some additional functionality and style you could not have without the images that exist on the server.

My question is: since there is no way to put our own images into Rally*, is there a way to find all the images possible that might be at our disposal on the server?  I've used the "resources" tab in chrome and can find what is used by particular pages, but it is not complete, only what is used.

My specific need is that I'm trying to make a grid that shows metric, and I want a column that shows a green up/down arrow if the trend is good, and a red up/down arrow if the trend is bad.

*: Second answer below shows this is incorrect: you can put attachments into rally and then refer to them in apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to incorporate icons is to use the icon classes:

```
<span class="icon-NAME"></span>
```

You could customize the colors by changing the font color in the CSS:

```
<span class="icon-arrow-down" style="color:red"></span>
```

Here are the available icons I've been able to find:

```
icon-add
icon-add-column
icon-addTag
icon-admin
icon-archive
icon-arrow-down
icon-arrow-left
icon-arrow-right
icon-arrow-up
icon-attachment
icon-back
icon-bars
icon-bell
icon-blocked
icon-board
icon-box
icon-calendar
icon-cancel
icon-change-set
icon-chat
icon-chevron-down
icon-chevron-left
icon-chevron-right
icon-chevron-up
icon-children
icon-circle
icon-close
icon-collapse
icon-color
icon-comment
icon-cone
icon-cross
icon-dashboard
icon-defect
icon-defectSuite
icon-delete
icon-deploy
icon-donut
icon-dots
icon-down
icon-down_full
icon-down_hollow
icon-download
icon-drag
icon-dropdown
icon-edit
icon-embed
icon-empty
icon-enlarge
icon-expand
icon-export
icon-favorite
icon-feedback
icon-file
icon-filter
icon-fiveDots
icon-flag
icon-folder
icon-full-arrow-down
icon-full-arrow-left
icon-full-arrow-right
icon-full-arrow-up
icon-gear
icon-graph
icon-grid
icon-help
icon-hierarchy
icon-history
icon-home
icon-hourglass
icon-idea
icon-images
icon-infinity
icon-info
icon-info-circle
icon-leaf
icon-leave
icon-left
icon-line
icon-link
icon-lock
icon-lock-open
icon-mail
icon-minus
icon-more
icon-next
icon-none
icon-not-favorite
icon-ok
icon-partial
icon-pie
icon-plus
icon-popup
icon-portfolio
icon-post
icon-predecessor
icon-previous
icon-print
icon-program
icon-progress
icon-question
icon-ready
icon-recycle
icon-refresh
icon-reply-all
icon-right
icon-right_full
icon-right_hollow
icon-rss
icon-save
icon-scope-down
icon-scope-up
icon-scope-up-down
icon-search
icon-setup
icon-share
icon-shrink
icon-small-chevron-down
icon-small-chevron-left
icon-small-chevron-right
icon-small-chevron-up
icon-snapshot
icon-split
icon-square
icon-story
icon-successor
icon-tag
icon-task
icon-test
icon-test-run
icon-testCase
icon-testSet
icon-threeDots
icon-thumbs-down
icon-thumbs-up
icon-to-do
icon-triangle
icon-up
icon-upload
icon-user
icon-user-add
icon-users
icon-visible
icon-warning
icon-workspace
```

[image]

Comment: This could be exactly what I was looking for...but I tried this by adding a xtype: 'container', html: <span ...as per above..., and I see in console: GET https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/images/icon-arrow-up.gif 404 (Not Found) .  Do I have to load some module or something?

Comment: I've experienced icons failing to load in the App-debug.html page before, but they always load for me in production. This seems to be only for certain browsers though. I've had the most luck with Chrome when using the debug page.

Comment: Also, I was able to do a little more digging. Looks like they're using Font Awesome which has WAY more icons than I've listed here. You can view the others here: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ Rather than using class="fa fa-ICON_NAME" just use class="icon-ICON_NAME". Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok-- this works for rc2 but not rc1-- not sure if perhaps Rally just enabled in rc2 or rc1 was broken.  And (annoyingly) it does not work locally in debug, but only running on Rally.  But it does work!  Thanks...

Comment: Also, unfortunately the full suite of Font Awesome stuff does not seem to be there, specifically arrow-circle-*.  Not sure what is in and what is out.

Comment: I believe these are not fontawsome icons, these are Rally icons. Notice the last icon - this is workspace picker icon in Rally.

Answer (score 3):

When I attach an image to a Rally artifact in my workspace it gives me a unique URL that I can use as follows:

```
 var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',{
        layout: 'hbox',
        itemId: 'p',
        items:[{
            xtype: 'image',
            autoRender: true,
            src: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/attachment/12345678/pic.png',
            width: 1000,
            height: 200
            }
        ]
        });
```